# VS Emulator: Adb.exe not found

Tags: visual-studio, android-studio, adb, visual-studio-emulator

This is the error I get when I try to install gapps (obtained from [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/qmd7z9x5ndsb54k/gapps-kk-20140105-signed.zip), following [these instructions](http://www.alteridem.net/2017/02/02/installing-google-play-gapps-visual-studio-android-emulators/)).

[image]

I navigated to  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` as instructed in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#LW_CollapsibleArea_Title), but I didn't found any "Android SDK Tools" folder:

[image]

which is weird because I do have Android SDK tools installed:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The accepted solution here is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404216/vs-emulator-adb-exe-not-found but doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 14):

Adding the key manually in the registry fixed it for me.

1. Type regedit.exe
2. Find the following node:

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\

Add:

- Key: Android SDK Tools
- String Value: Path with the Path to your sdk

[image: RegEdit Image]

Answer (score 1):

The other answer didn't work for me but I stumbled on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57228513/1978687) that points out (in #5) that newer versions expect the parent folder for `platform-tools` rather than the folder itself.